# python chat using poll

Tags: python, chat

I need to built a python chat and I'm stacked in the very final step. I've built the server and the client and I have the following problem while running the code:

- server.py 127.0.0.1
  -in a separate window client.py 127.0.0.1
  -another client
  -type the nicknames to chat for both clients and get the correct answer 'yuppie' meaning you are connected
- a client try to speak
- message is not read by the other client until it doesn't print something, after printing it get the message printed on its screen correctly.

I'd like to get the message without being obliged to print something, it's pretty unrealistic!!! Code of client and server are below in 2 different classes. Thank you!

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import socket,sys,select,re

PORT=1060  

class Server():


    def __init__(self,host):
        #building listen_sock  
        self.listen_sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.listen_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        self.listen_sock.bind((host,PORT))
        self.listen_sock.listen(20)
        #building dict for socket and socket state
        self.sockets={self.listen_sock.fileno(): self.listen_sock}
        self.socket_state={self.listen_sock.fileno():''}
        #building poll object
        self.poll=select.poll()
        self.poll.register(self.listen_sock,select.POLLIN)
        #users' list
        self.users_list={}



        #DON'T LOOK HERE
        #initialize the sender
        #self.sender=0

     #   self.users=re.compile("\s*\$(get users connected)$\s*",re.IGNORECASE)
      #  self.nick=re.compile("\s*\$\$(\w*\d*)\$\$\s*",re.IGNORECASE)
       # self.quit=re.compile("\s*\$(quit)\$\s*",re.IGNORECASE)
        #self.commands=[self.users,self.nick,self.quit]




    #funcion to receive message from client (work well)
    def recv_until(self,fd,suffix):
        self.message=''
        #checking the end of the message
        while not self.message.endswith(suffix):
            data=self.sockets[fd].recv(16)
            if not data:
                raise EOFError('socket closed before we saw %r' % suffix)
            self.message+=data    
        self.message=self.message[:-1]


   #delete client (work well)
    def del_client(self,fd):
        del self.users_list[fd]
        del self.socket_state[fd]
        self.poll.unregister(fd)

       #print the remaining active connections
        if not len(self.users_list):
            print 'Anyone is connected, waiting for new connection'
        else:
            print self.users_list



    #add new client and change the of the file descriptor for that client (work well)
    def new_client(self,fd):
        newsock, sockname = self.listen_sock.accept()
        print 'new connection from ', newsock.getpeername()
        newsock.setblocking(False)
        #recording the new connection
        fd=newsock.fileno()
        self.sockets[fd]=newsock
        self.poll.register(fd,select.POLLOUT)
        self.socket_state[fd]='ask nick'




 #DON'T LOOK HERE 
 #   def handle_query(self,fd):


  #      for n,command in enumerate(self.commands):

   #         match=command.search(self.message)


    #        if n==1 and match:

     #           self.users_list[self.sockets[fd].getpeername()]=match.group(1)
      #          print self.users_list

       #         for value in self.users_list.values():
        #            self.sockets[fd].sendall(value+'\n')




    #starting the main function of the class
    def chat(self):

        while True: 
            #here il where the code hangs up waitng and waiting (WORKS BAD)
            #return a tuple, identify where (fd) the event (event) is happening
            for fd,event in self.poll.poll():
                #print the state of each socket and the poll object
                print self.socket_state
                print self.poll.poll()


                #starting the state machine

                #remove closed sockets
                if event & (select.POLLHUP | select.POLLERR | 
                select.POLLNVAL): 
                    #deleting the socket closed at fd
                    self.del_client(fd)


                #if the socket referred to is our listen_sock and we have a new connection request   
                elif self.sockets[fd] is self.listen_sock:
                    #recording the new entry!
                    self.new_client(fd)




                #managing all the situation where it is necessary to answer to a client
                #and changing the state of the socket and that of the sockets[fd]
                elif event & select.POLLOUT:

                    if self.socket_state[fd]=='ask nick':
                        self.sockets[fd].sendall('identify\n')
                        self.poll.modify(self.sockets[fd],select.POLLIN)
                        self.socket_state[fd]='get user'

                    if self.socket_state[fd]=='invalid nick':
                        self.sockets[fd].sendall('invalid nick\n')
                        for value in self.users_list.values():
                            self.sockets[fd].sendall('\n'+value+'\n')
                        self.socket_state[fd]='ask nick'

                    if self.socket_state[fd]=='connected':
                        print '3'
                        self.sockets[fd].sendall('yuppie\n')
                        self.poll.modify(self.sockets[fd],select.POLLIN)
                        self.socket_state[fd]='ready to communicate'

                    if self.socket_state[fd]=='ready to receive':
                        self.sockets[fd].sendall(self.message)
                        print '4'
                        self.poll.modify(self.sockets[fd],select.POLLIN)
                        self.socket_state[fd]='ready to communicate'




                #managing all the situation where it is necessary to get values from clients
                elif event & select.POLLIN:

                    if self.socket_state[fd]=='get user':

                        self.recv_until(fd,'\n')

                        if self.message not in self.users_list.values():
                            self.users_list[fd]=self.message
                            self.poll.modify(self.sockets[fd],select.POLLOUT)
                            self.socket_state[fd]='connected'
                        else:
                            self.poll.modify(self.sockets[fd],select.POLLOUT)
                            self.socket_state[fd]='invalid nick'

                    if self.socket_state[fd]=='ready to communicate':
                        self.recv_until(fd,'\n')
                        print '5'
                        for i in self.users_list.keys():
                            if i!=fd:
                                self.poll.modify(self.sockets[i],select.POLLOUT)
                                self.socket_state[i]='ready to receive'




if __name__ == '__main__':
    se=Server(sys.argv[1])
    se.chat()






#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys,socket,select,threading,time

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

HOST=sys.argv.pop()
PORT=1060


class Client():


    def setup(self):

        server_address=(HOST,PORT)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(server_address)



    def chat(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            text=raw_input('>>> ')
            self.sock.sendall(text+'\n')




    def rec(self):
        while True:
            mess=self.sock.recv(16)
            if mess:
                print '$$$ ', mess,


    def start(self):
        l=threading.Thread(target=self.rec)
        t=threading.Thread(target=self.chat)


        t.start()
        l.start()


if __name__=='__main__':
    cl=Client()
    cl.setup()
    cl.start()
```

Comment: solved! it was a problem of output flushing! It goes well adding sys.stdout.flush() inside the while of the method chat in the client or removing the comma from the print always in the same chat method (the \n flushes the output)

Answer (score 0):

Next time take a look at http://www.zeromq.org/, it has a nice python binding http://zeromq.github.com/pyzmq/. It's perfect for this kind of stuff.